# In Webforms MVP (ASP.NET), who should set the data of dynamically created usercontrol, view or presenter?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, webformsmvp

I'm trying to refactor a Webforms application to Model-View-Presenter (MVP) using the WebformsMVP framework. While creating presenters and adapting view code, I've come across one view which dynamically fills the data of some of its subcontrols. Here is the code behind of the non-refactored version of the view I'm working on:

```
[PresenterBinding(typeof(OrderDetailsPresenter))]
public partial class OrderDetails : AuthorizedPageBase<OrderDetailsPage>, IOrderDetails
{
    private PurchaseOrder _orderDetail;

    private int _orderGroupId;

    protected new void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Page_Load(sender, e);

        _orderGroupId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["po"])
            ? _orderGroupId = 0
            : _orderGroupId = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["po"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        _orderDetail = OrderContext.Current.GetPurchaseOrder(SecurityContext.Current.CurrentContactId, _orderGroupId);

        if (_orderDetail == null)
            return;

        if (_orderDetail.OrderForms[0].Shipments.Count > 1)
        {
            var control = (OrderDetailsMultiShipment)LoadControl("~/Templates/Sample/Units/AccountManagement/OrderDetailsMultiShipment.ascx");
            control.OrderDetail = _orderDetail;
            modulePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(control);
        }
        else
        {
            var control = (OrderDetailsSingleShipment)LoadControl("~/Templates/Sample/Units/AccountManagement/OrderDetailsSingleShipment.ascx");
            control.OrderDetail = _orderDetail;
            modulePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(control);
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, depending of the values, one control or another is loaded with several information. My idea is to:

- Move PurchaseOrder property to the presenter
- Try to move as much logic as possible from the Page_Load
- Refactor the controls to be plain and don't fill any OrderDetail attribute (The most confusing problem for me)

I tried the following approach to solve these issues(create an event that the presenter fills with data, and then is checked by the view):

```
[PresenterBinding(typeof(OrderDetailsPresenter))]
public partial class OrderDetails : AuthorizedPageBase<OrderDetailsPage>, IOrderDetails
{
    public event EventHandler<GetShipmentsArgs> GetShipments;

    protected new void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Page_Load(sender, e);

        var args = new GetShipmentsArgs();
        GetShipments(this, args);

        if (args.Shipments.Count > 1)
        {
            var control = (OrderDetailsMultiShipment)LoadControl("~/Templates/Sample/Units/AccountManagement/OrderDetailsMultiShipment.ascx");
            control.OrderDetail = _orderDetail; //Here I duplicate the problem I tried to solve...
            modulePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(control);
        }
        else
        {
            var control = (OrderDetailsSingleShipment)LoadControl("~/Templates/Sample/Units/AccountManagement/OrderDetailsSingleShipment.ascx");
            control.OrderDetail = _orderDetail; //Here I duplicate the problem I tried to solve...
            modulePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(control);
        }
    }
```

Yes, I know my code doesn't compile, but I hope it clarifies my idea. My approach still has several problems:
- View still has logic about to decide which control to load, and has to load information for the control to be loaded.

I thought about a system of inter-presenter communication, but I'm not sure if it is the best solution. Which would be the best way to refactor my initial code on a MVP paradigm?

Thank you

Comment: I respect WebformsMVP, but if you have to update that much of changes, why not ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: @Win on the project I'm working on, that's not really an option due to time restrictions...